Veeam vCenter backup - accessing incorrect IP address of VMware node
Being new to VEEAM, I might be troubleshooting problem that's trivial for VEEAM experts.
On Veeam 12.2 and vCenter 8.0.3, my problem is ESXi hosts having multiple networks which causes Veeam's confusion. There's management network and there's vMotion network. The hosts in vCenter are defined as follows:

The problem is, Veeam isn't able to back up a single VM. The log is full of these errors:
22.10.2024 11:17:51.481] <  1436> vdl      | [vddk] CnxOpenTCPSocket: Cannot connect to server 172.16.0.13:902: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
[22.10.2024 11:17:51.481] <  1436> vdl      | [vddk] CnxAuthdConnect: Returning false because CnxAuthdConnectTCP failed
[22.10.2024 11:17:51.481] <  1436> vdl      | [vddk] CnxConnectAuthd: Returning false because CnxAuthdConnect failed
[22.10.2024 11:17:51.481] <  1436> vdl      | [vddk] Cnx_Connect: Returning false because CnxConnectAuthd failed
[22.10.2024 11:17:51.481] <  1436> vdl      | [vddk] Cnx_Connect: Error message: Failed to connect to server 172.16.0.13:902
[22.10.2024 11:17:51.481] <  1436> vdl      | WARN|[vddk] warn [NFC ERROR]NfcNewAuthdConnectionEx: Failed to connect: Failed to connect to server 172.16.0.13:902
[22.10.2024 11:17:51.481] <  1436> vdl      | WARN|[vddk] warn [NFC ERROR]NfcNewAuthdConnectionEx: Failed to connect to peer. Error: Failed to connect to server 172.16.0.13:902
[22.10.2024 11:17:51.481] <  1436> vdl      | WARN|[vddk] warn [NFC ERROR]NfcEstablishAuthCnxToServer: Failed to create new AuthD connection: Failed to connect to server 172.16.0.13:902
[22.10.2024 11:17:51.481] <  1436> vdl      | WARN|[vddk] warn [NFC ERROR]Nfc_BindAndEstablishAuthdCnx3: Failed to create a connection with server 172.16.0.13: Failed to connect to server 172.16.0.13:902
[22.10.2024 11:17:51.481] <  1436> vdl      | [vddk] NBD_ClientOpen: Couldn't connect to 10.250.100.13:902 Failed to connect to server 172.16.0.13:902

It's worth noting 172.16.0.0/24 is not accessible outside of VMWare (i.e. also unreachable for VEEAM).
How can I make Veeam to connect to 10.250.100.0/24 and not 172.16.0.0/24?
During the vCenter "object" configuration in VEEAM, the connection from VEEAM to vCenter works perfectly (correct credentials, network visibility, ...)
Thanks in advance

Why are you editing under different ServerFault user?

By mistake. It won't happen again.

Problem solved.
For others stumbling upon this trouble, this might help you: In my case, the ESXi hosts have multiple NICs (vMotion, management, ...). The network visible from VEEAM's point of view is only the management one (vMotion is invisible to VEEAM). If you have vSphere NFC backup traffic type enabled on your vMotion (or any other vNET invisible to VEEAM) and disabled where it should be enabled, you get the result I was getting in the original post.

